# If column with name contains partial value, keep rows

Tags: r, grepl

I have a dataset:

```
Camp1    Ade2    Camp3    Ade4    
   dA       1       eB       2
   dB       4       uC       8
   gB       3       NA      NA
```

How do I subset this dataset where if a column name that has "Camp" in the name does not contain values "A" or "B" or NA, exclude those rows.

I know how do it for exact matches but not partial.

```
cols = grepl("Camp", names(df))
rows = rowSums(df[, cols] == "A" | 
df[, cols] == "B" |
is.na(df[, cols])) == sum(cols)
df<-df[rows, ]
```

How do I do the equivalent but with partial matches?

Expected Output:

```
Camp1    Ade2    Camp3    Ade4    
   dA       1       eB       2
   gB       3       NA      NA
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: sorry about that @markus, is this more clear?

Comment: But the second row contains a `"B"` in column `Camp1`

Comment: right but 2nd row for Camp3 does not contain A, B, or NA. Therefore that row needs to be excluded

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R you can try:

```
df_cols <- df[, grepl("Camp", names(df))]
df[apply(df_cols, 1, function(x) all(grepl("A|B", x) | is.na(x))), ]

  Camp1 Ade2 Camp3 Ade4
1    dA    1    eB    2
3    gB    3  <NA>   NA
```

In the first step it identifies the columns that contains "Camp" in their name and then subset the data based on the given condition.

Comment: all answers were great, this one gave the most flexible for my specific dataset. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `filter_at` from `dplyr`. Using the `starts_with` helper function, we apply the filter to every column that starts with `'Camp'`. On those columns, we filter on rows where `all_vars` contain `A` or `B` or `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Camp")), all_vars(grepl('A|B', .) | is.na(.)))
```

**Output:**

```
  Camp1 Ade2 Camp3 Ade4
1    dA    1    eB    2
2    gB    3  <NA>   NA
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Camp1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("dA", "dB", 
"gB"), class = "factor"), Ade2 = c(1L, 4L, 3L), Camp3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, NA), .Label = c("eB", "uC"), class = "factor"), Ade4 = c(2L, 
8L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse-style solution.

#### Using `filter_at`:

```
my_df %>%
    filter_at(vars(matches('Camp')), all_vars(is.na(.) | str_detect(., 'A|B')))
```

Here, `vars(matches('Camp'))` says to filter columns whose names contain the string `Camp`, and the `all_vars(...)` says to keep only the rows where *all* columns [that match 'Camp'] meet the specified criteria.

You will need to do `require(tidyverse)` and `require(stringr)` for this to work.